# vb2010 Getting Button Name on MouseDown Event

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How do I capture the name of a button so I can use it in another form to query a database. I am new to vb and still at the very early learning stage so any help would be greatfully appreciated.

frmMain

```
Private Sub btnA_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnA.MouseDown
        If (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right) Then
            frmRacks.Show()
        ElseIf (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Left clicked")
        End If
    End Sub
```

frmRacks

Here is where I need to capture name to query database

Comment: You mean the Windows Form button?

Comment: Hi Edper Yes. I have button on frmMain called btnA. I need to capture the name in frmRacks to query database. Thanks

Comment: It would be a fair miracle if the button's name isn't "btnA".  You have only one Handles clause on the event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, one is to declare public field/variable in frmRack, another is using ShowDialog instead of Show:

I'll go with the first one (public) first:

```
Public buttonName as String
```

And in the button click from your frmMain you pass the value like:

```
Private Sub btnA_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnA.MouseDown
    If (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right) Then
       frmRacks.buttonName = "btnA" ' Or you could use DirectCast as proposed by dbasnett
       frmRacks.Show()
    ElseIf (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Left clicked")
    End If
End Sub
```

And then in Loading your frmRacks you have now the option of assigning button Name, like:

```
Private Sub frmRacks_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim query as String =  "SELECT * FROM " + buttonName 'This is only an example you could make your own here
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that Edper. Just one more thing. If I have a label that needs to use this value would it be lblRacks.Text = buttonName which is a label in frmRacks. Because when I do this I get is lblRacks is not declared. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseDown
    Dim name As String = DirectCast(sender, Button).Name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `MouseButtons.Left` instead of `Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left`

```
If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
    MsgBox("Left Button Clicked") 'OR WHATEVER YOU WANT IT TO DO?!
End If
```

Comment: How does that help me capture the name. Thanks

Comment: what do you want exactly??

Comment: I have button on frmMain called btnA. I need to capture the name in frmRacks to query database. Thanks